# Facebook Profile Picture not showing up in Navigation Header?

Tags: java, android, xml, facebook

I have a simple `NavigationView` in which I try to show my profile picture. This is what I have so far:

MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        Profile profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();
        System.out.println("Profile Id: " + profile.getId());
        ProfilePictureView profilePictureView = (ProfilePictureView) findViewById(R.id.profile_image);
        if(profilePictureView != null) {
            System.out.println("Not null.");
            System.out.println("Profile Name: " + profile.getFirstName());
            profilePictureView.setProfileId(profile.getId());
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Null.");
        }
    }
}
```

main_activity.xml:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true" tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include layout="@layout/app_bar_news_feed" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start" android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_news_feed">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <include layout="@layout/nav_header_news_feed"
                android:id="@+id/navigation_header"/>

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/friends_list"
                android:layout_weight="7"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"></ListView>

        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

nav_header_news_feed.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/nav_header_height"
    xmlns:facebook="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:background="@drawable/side_nav_bar"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="bottom">

    <com.facebook.login.widget.ProfilePictureView
        android:id="@+id/profile_image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        facebook:com_facebook_preset_size="small"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

I am very confused because I thought that I had to simply instantiate the `profilePictureView` object and set its profile id. I thought I was doing everything right because the first name matches with the user that is logged in, and I have made sure that the user ID is not null.

Rather, the picture just looks like an empty Facebook profile picture when in reality I know I have a photo. If anyone could point me in the right direction, that would be great. Thanks!

EDIT: Added in edits to my files to mirror what Mattia Maestrini suggested:

MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    private NavigationView navigationView;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
        View header = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.nav_header_news_feed, null);
        navigationView.addHeaderView(header);

        Profile profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();
        System.out.println("Profile Id: " + profile.getId());
        ProfilePictureView profilePictureView = (ProfilePictureView) header.findViewById(R.id.profile_image);
        if(profilePictureView != null) {
            System.out.println("Not null.");
            System.out.println("Profile Name: " + profile.getFirstName());
            profilePictureView.setProfileId(profile.getId());
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Null.");
        }
    }
}
```

main_activity.xml:

```
<include layout="@layout/app_bar_news_feed" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start" android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <include layout="@layout/nav_header_news_feed"
            android:id="@+id/navigation_header"/>

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/friends_list"
            android:layout_weight="7"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"></ListView>

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
```

Comment: Have you  write these `FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(context);
        callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create(); `  in onCreate method before getting AccessToken  ?

Comment: @rushankshah yes I have but I have done so in my login activity which, after the user logs in, goes to the MainActivity.java. If I did not do this, the AccessToken would be null. Do I need to call those functions in this file also?

Comment: Is your token null or it has the value after login ?

Comment: @rushankshah it has a value. I confirmed it by printing out the access token user id which exists.

Comment: If it has the token and userid then it must be show image of users.

Comment: @rushankshah hm but it doesn't. which is why I am asking the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `NavigationView` has a [bug](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=190226) in v23.1.0 of support library. You can't access to the views contained in the `HeaderView` in `onCreate` method.

A workaround is to inflate the `HeaderView` and add it programatically. Remove `app:headerLayout` from `main_activity.xml` and then change `onCreate` like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        Profile profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();
        System.out.println("Profile Id: " + profile.getId());

        View header = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.nav_header_news_feed, null);
        navigationView.addHeaderView(header);

        ProfilePictureView profilePictureView = (ProfilePictureView) header.findViewById(R.id.profile_image);
        if(profilePictureView != null) {
            System.out.println("Not null.");
            System.out.println("Profile Name: " + profile.getFirstName());
            profilePictureView.setProfileId(profile.getId());
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Null.");
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT**: Since you already add the header with the include tag:

```
<include layout="@layout/nav_header_news_feed"
        android:id="@+id/navigation_header"/>
```

You can remove the custom inflation of the header in `MainActivity.java`:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        Profile profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();
        System.out.println("Profile Id: " + profile.getId());
        ProfilePictureView profilePictureView = (ProfilePictureView) findViewById(R.id.profile_image);
        if(profilePictureView != null) {
            System.out.println("Not null.");
            System.out.println("Profile Name: " + profile.getFirstName());
            profilePictureView.setProfileId(profile.getId());
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Null.");
        }
    }
}
```

And you don't need to specify the `app:headerLayout` in `main_activity.xml`:

```
<include 
    layout="@layout/app_bar_news_feed" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView 
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start" 
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <include 
            layout="@layout/nav_header_news_feed"
            android:id="@+id/navigation_header"/>

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/friends_list"
            android:layout_weight="7"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"></ListView>

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
```

Comment: Hi, unfortunately this method did not work. I followed all your instructions. I  have added edits to my answer above to show what I did. I verified that my profile id and such were not null.

Comment: I just noted that you have a `LinearLayout` inside the `NavigationView`, can i ask why? In this way you have two header, with two `ProfilePictureView`, this is what cause your error, you set the image in the invisible one. Remove the `LinearLayout` and it should works.

Comment: If I remove the first `LinearLayout`, I cannot get my list view I want to show that is below my navigation header. If I remove the `include` for the layout, I cannot get my navigation header to show. `nav_header_news_feed.xml` also needs a `LinearLayout` for the `xmlns:facebook="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"` namespace to change the size of the picture.

Comment: I actually fixed it. Thank you for your help. Since I have a `Listview` below the header that you prescribed above, how do I make it so that the `Listview` appears below the header?

Comment: I just updated my answer. With this method you will have a `ListView` below the header. Let me know if it works for you.